# Feature extraction from spectrum to aid categorisation

Tags: signal-analysis

i have two sets of signals whose spectrum looks like shown in the figure. The first column of signals belongs to category 1 and the second belongs to category 2.
Looking at the spectrums I want to identify features which will differentiate the two.
Eg:mean,variance etc.

[image: Column 1 and Column 2]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I am trying to make **Content Based Music Recommendation system** based from Music signal features characteristics. Which Music signal features are possible to use? How to extract them? Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

First thing to mention is that you must have some kind of Machine Learning algorithm to perform your recognition. You might want to use the following - what's yours?

- Neural Networks (easy to implement)
- SVM's (should perform best)
- k-NN (eventually, but needs lot's of data to store)

Regarding features, it's hard to determine which to use for your application just by looking at spectra - both of categories have peaks at lower and higher part of range. Also there might be some significant information in time domain or a specific method valid for processing this type of signals. You never said what these signals are and what's the application.

The only thing I notice is that class 2 has some harmonic content occurring at frequencies $160 \mathtt{Hz}$, and $200 - 225 \mathtt{Hz}$. I don't think that simple mean and variance will do. Probably you should try different and choose best performing ones. My suggestions of features you've asked for (to start with), are:

- **Spectral Slope** (what's the gradient of the linear regression of your spectrum)
- **Audio Spectrum Flatness** (calculated in frequency banks - tells you if signal is noisy or harmonic)
- **Audio Spectrum Centroid** (kind of 'mean value' you mentioned)
- **Audio Spectrum Envelope** (can be understood as very general spectrum descriptor - envelope)
- **MFCC** (well defined and described - they are describing your spectrum by using cepstral analysis)

For more info about implementations you can refer to this great book (easy to get): [MPEG-7 Audio and Beyond](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/047009334X).

Answer (score 3):

I've successfully distinguished such spectra using a fairly simple feature. After calculating the FFT and then energy per bin, sum all bins to get the total energy and then sort the bins *by their energy*, highest first. Calculate the total energy in the first `N` bins until that exceeds 90% of the total energy.

The spectra on the left will have 90% of their energy in just ~10% of the bins; the spectra on the right will have 90% of their energy in ~25% of the bins.

More formally, sort `E[]` by value descending, and then solve `Σ(i=0..N) E[i] = 0.9 * Σ E[i]` for N.